# Where does current go in these circuits?

Tags: current, audio, dc

In both these schematics, the 9V source drives current through the circuit, but there doesn't seem to be any way in which the current can 'return' to the source to complete the circuit. In what ways would current flow through both these circuits from the DC source, and where would the current end up? Wouldn't all the current just go to ground? This is for an audio circuit, input is from a electric instrument and output goes to the speakers/recording equipment.

[image: Circuit 1]

[image: Circuit 2]

Comment: Current flows (conventional) from (+) terminal to GND. The (-) terminal is connected to GND.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is implied that the 9 V source has its negative end connected to ground.  Current therefore flows out the positive end of the 9 V source, into the circuit, out the circuit's ground connection, and back into the negative end of the 9 V source.

### Added

As Dave Tweed pointed out in a comment, and I didn't notice ealier, the second circuit uses a positive ground.  In that case, current flows out the positive end of the 9 V supply into the circuit ground, thru the circuit to the -9V connection, and back into the negative input of the 9 V source.

The common thread in both cases is that ground is implied as the 0 V reference for all other voltages that don't explicitly specify a reference.  Both the "+9v DC" point in the top circuit and the "-9v" point in the bottom circuit are therefore relative to ground.  Since they are labeled as supply points, it is assumed that a power supply is connected between these points and ground.

Comment: However, note that the second circuit is positive-ground.

Comment: @Dave: Sorry I didn't notice that before.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

The actual 9 volt supply is not shown. In these cases, the default assumption is that it is connected to ground, so current returns to the supply via circuit ground.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a shift in notation to simplify circuit design especially in electronics. One must be sure of the fact that fundamentals are not at all different.

1. There is current flow when there is potential difference.
2. Current flows from higher to lower potential.

This notation is basically extension to the concept of positive terminal used to provide voltage and negative is grounded with other wires. In fact if you redraw the circuit using that concept you will be free from confusion.